# How would I get an alert to appear when I click on an a button in a class?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have several buttons in my webpage in the 'addbutton' class and I want an alert to pop up any time any one of them is clicked. How would you do this?
Here are some JS pieces of code I have already tried (that have not worked):

```
addbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("addbutton")
           addbuttons.onclick {
           for (var i=0; i<addbuttons.length; i++) {
               alert("hi")
           }
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("addbutton").onclick = function() {
alert("hi")}
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"> 
            <p>Breakfast:</p>
            <button class="addbutton">+</button>
            <div></div>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <p>Mid-Morning:</p>
            <button class="addbutton">+</button>
            <div></div>
            <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define your event:

```
function myEvent() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Now let's get your elements by class name, loop them and add an event listener to them:

```
for (let btn of document.getElementsByClassName("addbutton")) btn.addEventListener("click", myEvent);
```

Your mistake was that you assumed that you have an `onclick` for the set of elements, returned by `getElementsByClassName`, however, you only have `onclick` for the elements inside the set.

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementsByClassName("addbutton")` returns an Array(`HTMLCollection` to be precise).
Also, you need to set the onclick to a function, you cannot use the syntax `.onclick { }`.

To set a listener for every button you will need to use a for loop somewhat like this

```
for(let i = 0; i < addbuttons.length; i++){
    addbuttons[i].onclick = function(){
        alert('Works!')
    }
}
```

Or if you are using ES6

```
for(let addButton of addbuttons){
    addButton.onclick = function(){
        alert('Works!')
    }
}
```

Probably relevant links,

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp